# The Kernel in Jupyter Notebook does not respond when importing the ROOT framework

Tags: jupyter-notebook, root-framework, pyroot, jupyter-kernel

I am hoping to use pyRoot, the data analysis framework developed by CERN, by integrating it in a Jupyter notebook. That said, I believe that I did the proper installation of ROOT on my macOS 10.

When I launch the ROOT Jupyter notebook using the following command, it launches properly:

```
root --notebook
```

and I get the Jupyter notebook editor. However, whenever I start the notebook by:

```
import ROOT
```

The command is kept loading a pop up notification telling me that:

```
The kernel appears to have died. It will restart automatically.
```

Comment: is there some error printout on the command line where you started jupyter? or any other logs? is root built for the same python version as jupyter or do oyu have one in python2, the other in python3?

Comment: I checked I have root installed for python 3 and I have python 3 installed.